# Differentiation is not a bounded linear operator

Tags: normed-spaces

A common example of a linear operator which is not bounded is that of differentiation, with a suitable domain. If the domain is, say,$P[0,1]$, (The set of polynomials on the interval $[0,1]$) with the $\sup$ norm, then it is clear that differentiation is not bounded, since if there were a positive $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

\begin{align}
\lVert p'(x) \rVert \leq c\lVert p(x) \rVert 
\end{align}

We could find a natural number $n_c$ which is larger than $c$, and obtain a contradiction by noting that

$$\lVert \frac{d}{dx}x^{n_c} \rVert = n_c > c $$

However, the course I am currently doing presents the example of differentiation as a linear operator from $P_n[0,1]$ to itself, and then proceed to state that this is *still* not bounded; however I fail to see why, it seems that we could simply take $c = n$, and everything will be perfectly fine. Is there something I am missing, or is this just a blatant mistake?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, any linear operator between finite-dimensional spaces must be bounded.

Comment: @DarkMagician ah of course, simply take the maximum value of the norms of the operator applied to the different (unit) basis vectors, hadn't  thought of that, thanks!